# microsoft band workout plan IDE

Tags: microsoft-band

Does anyone know what tool/format Workout Plans for the Microsoft Band are created with?  I would like to create(copy) my own Marathon Training plan since I haven't found any already created.  The dashboard allows you to create a workout, but it doesn't allow you to string them together into a plan (like the couch to 5k plan).
Any leads/hacks would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe creating a plan is currently supported. But it is probably something that Microsoft could easily add.

As such, your best bet would be to ask for the capability on the Microsoft Health User Voice:
http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band

They've added new features asked for from the UserVoice before.

Comment: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band/suggestions/10492062-allow-users-to-make-their-own-custom-workout-plans#comments